# How to print a's in between this grid

Tags: python, function

[image]

Not able to place 'a' between the lines 
I was able to write the code for only the grid :

```
def draw_grid_art_four():
  a = "+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +"
  def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()

  def do_four(f):
      do_twice(f)
      do_twice(f)
  def vertical():
      b = "|         |         |         |"
      print(b)
  print(a)
  do_four(vertical)
  print(a)
  do_four(vertical)
  print(a)
  do_four(vertical)
  print(a)
  do_four(vertical)
  print(a)


draw_grid_art_four()
```

Also it would be helpful if you can suggest me how to make this code shorter
( I am  a beginner )

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment? Asking so that answers may be tailored accordingly

Comment: This is a assignment by my institution

Comment: Hint: can you spot in your code a place from which the *empty* cells go from? Try to change the empty cells with cells filled with letters.

Comment: @Alex yup got it but I was asked to write the code in form of function of three parameters `def pattern_gen(s, rows, cols):` where `s` is the character that will be repeated in the pattern,`rows` will be no of cells in a rows and `cols` similarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always approach your logic at a general level (e.g. using variables for dimensions). this will allow you to really understand the process and avoid mistakes and repetitions:

```
rows,cols    = 4,3
height,width = 2,4
frame   = "+" + "+".join(["-"*width]*cols) + "+"   # +---+---...  Frame line
content = frame.replace("+","|").replace("-","a")  # |aaa|aaa...  Content line
for _ in range(rows):
    print(frame)             # print a frame line before each row's content block
    for _ in range(height):
        print(content)       # print a content lines for a row's height
print(frame)                 # print a closing frame line at the end
```

output:

```
+----+----+----+
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
+----+----+----+
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
+----+----+----+
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
+----+----+----+
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
|aaaa|aaaa|aaaa|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This really helped.Actually as I have just started learning I didn't know how to use ```.replace``` and ```.join``` yet.I will try to implement your advice in further problems

Answer (score 2):

Try to use recursive function as below, it is easier to code and also read. Are you looking for something like that?

```
def displayA(col, index):
    if index == 0:
        return
    print(col * '| a a a a ' + '|')
    return displayA(col, index-1)

def repeat(row, col):
    if row == 0:
        return
    print(col * '+ - - - - ' + '+')
    displayA(col, col+1)
    return repeat(row-1, col)

def box(row, col): 
    repeat(row, col)
    print(col * '+ - - - - ' + '+')


box(4,3)

Output:
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
| a a a a | a a a a | a a a a |                                                                                                                                               
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +
```

Comment: This is really helpul.If I was supposed to write this code in the form of function of three parameters `def pattern_gen(s, rows, cols):` where `s` is the character that will be repeated in the pattern,`rows`will be no of cells in a rows and `cols` similarly,how could I do that?

Comment: What I meant that how can I add 'a' as a parameter of the function instead of printing it in  code

Comment: Ok! Just replace `print(col * '| a a a a ' + '|')` by `print(col * ('|  '+col * (s+'  ')) + '|')`. Don't forget to add `s` as a parameter of your function.